# CurrentCulture and SecurityException

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

We write some winForms GUI application that uses the Invariant Culture. So in the beginning of the Main we have:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        ...
```

The problem is that on some machines it works perfectly but on some machines on some configurations ( like Debug/AnyCPU fro x64 machines) it raises SequrityException

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

So what is the problem with it? And why it happens only on some conditions?

Comment: Can you show that the CultureInfo has anything to do with it?

Comment: It is the place where the exception is thrown and if I comment it there are no exceptions thrown. Or I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture) mentions security issues when using the invariant culture. Perhaps this is your issue?

> Using the InvariantCulture Property
>
> ```
> The InvariantCulture property represents neither a neutral nor a
> ```
>
> specific culture. It represents a third type of culture that is
>   culture-insensitive. It is associated with the English language but
>   not with a country or region. Your applications can use this property
>   with almost any method in the System.Globalization namespace that
>   requires a culture. However, an application should use the invariant
>   culture only for processes that require culture-independent results,
>   such as formatting and parsing data that is persisted to a file. In
>   other cases, it produces results that might be linguistically
>   incorrect or culturally inappropriate.
>
> ```
> Security Considerations If a security decision will be made based
> ```
>
> on the result of a string comparison or case change, your application
>   should use an ordinal comparison that ignores case instead of using
>   InvariantCulture. The default implementations of methods such as
>   Compare()()() and ToUpper use the CurrentCulture property. Code that
>   performs culture-sensitive string operations can cause security
>   vulnerabilities if CurrentCulture is changed or if the culture on the
>   computer running the code differs from the culture used to test the
>   code. The behavior that you expect when writing a string operation
>   differs from the actual behavior of your code on the executing
>   computer. In contrast, an ordinal comparison depends solely on the
>   binary value of the compared characters.
>
> ```
> String Operations If your application needs to perform a
> ```
>
> culture-sensitive string operation that is not affected by the value
>   of CurrentCulture, it should use a method that accepts a CultureInfo
>   parameter. The application should specify the value of the
>   InvariantCulture property for this parameter. The application should
>   use the property with methods such as Compare()()() and ToUpper to
>   eliminate cultural variations and ensure consistent results. For more
>   information about using the InvariantCulture property to perform
>   culture-insensitive string operations, see Culture-Insensitive String
>   Operations.
>
> ```
> Persisting Data The InvariantCulture property is useful for
> ```
>
> storing data that will not be displayed directly to users. Storing
>   data in a culture-independent format guarantees a known format that
>   does not change. When users from different cultures access the data,
>   it can be formatted appropriately based on specific user. For example,
>   if your application stores DateTime types in a text file, formatted
>   for the invariant culture, the application should use the
>   InvariantCulture property when calling ToString to store the strings
>   and the Parse method to retrieve the strings. This technique ensures
>   that the underlying values of the DateTime types do not change when
>   the data is read or written by users from different cultures.