# Get multidimensional array from text files

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have static class theat declare the array:

```
static class GlobalDataClass
{
    public static double[,] dDataArray = new double[10, 2];   
}
```

Now I have a function that stream the text file line by line by having the number of rows and index of the array:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    double[] dx = new double[lines]; //lines store number of rows
    double[] dy = new double[lines]; //lines store number of rows

    for (long li = 0; li < lines; li++)
    {
        dx[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 0];
        dy[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 1];
    }
}
```

My text file will be like:

```
1,2  
2,3  
3,4  
5,6
```

Now how to have the output matrix like:

```
dx[1] [0,0] = 1  
dy[1] [0,1] = 2
```

and so on.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how to have the output like above:

Answer (score 1):

For create multidimensional array, you can use list of list:

```
List<List<string>> ls = new List<List<string>>();
           var  filename="aa.txt";
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
           while (!sr.EndOfStream)
           {
               var line = sr.ReadLine();
               var element = line.Split(',');
               List<string> temp = new List<string>();
               foreach (var item in element)
               {
                   temp.Add(item);
               }
               ls.Add(temp);
           }
```

In this code, every line may have many element (>2).

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file and split each line at the comma, like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MyNumbers.txt");
String line;
String[] lineSeperate;
line = sr.ReadLine();
lineSeperate = line.Split(',');
```

now, `dx[index] = lineSeperate[0]` and `dy[index]=lineSeperate[1]`

**Edit**
You need to convert from String to double:

```
dx[0] = double.Parse(lineSeperate[0]);
dy[0] = double.Parse(lineSeperate[1]);
```

Comment: I got the error "connot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'". Any solution?

Comment: @Ren, offcourse. You need to convert from string to double. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp. I'll update the answer later.