# Convert ".1", ".2" to double

Tags: c#, double

I want to convert string like `".1"`, `".2"`, etc into `0.1`, `0.2` etc.

I tried:

```
Convert.ToDouble(".1")
```

and it crashes. I understand why it crashes, but I still need to convert it to valid double number. I know I can do this with splitting string and parsing but is there a better way?

Comment: It doesn't "crash", it throws an exception. Is your locale one that uses a comma for a decimal separator?

Comment: It doesn't even do that, [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hnDW6c), what error do you get? this works for me

Comment: @Sayse I get "System.FormatException"

Comment: Is this your real code ?

Comment: You can use the `ToDouble`-method that accepts an instance of `IFormatProvider` to provide a custom format.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Convert.ToDouble` uses current culture settings *by default*.

Probably your current culture has different string than `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator).

As a solution, you can use a culture that *already* has `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture), or your can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone) your `CurrentCulture`, set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` to `.` and use *that* cloned culture in your `Convert.ToDouble` method (or `double.Parse`) as a second parameter.

```
var d = double.Parse(".1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
var d = double.Parse(".1", clone);
```

Comment: Also gets me every time...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  Double result = Double.Parse(".1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

by specifing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` you ensure `.` to be a decimal separator.