# how do I do a multiplication calculation with a string (textbox) and a Double value in c#?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to create a program which is a hire program, I have stored 2 values as a double variable (the first one is set to the value £3.00 and the second one is set to £1.00 and I have a 2 text boxes:

1. The first textbox is where the user will type how many hours they want.
2. The second textbox will display the result of multiplying txtHours by costPerHour and adding £1.00 for insurance where required by the user.

The problem  I am having is that it is giving the following error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'double'

I have tried everything including the parse technique but it still won't work
could someone please take a look at the code below and tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double costPerHour = 3.00;
        double costOfInsurance = 1.00;

        if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
            txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text * costPerHour + costOfInsurance;
        else
            txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text * costPerHour;
    }
```

Comment: When you say "I have tried everything including the parse technique but it still won't work", what exactly have you tried, and what did it do that was different to what you expected?

Comment: Use `NumericUpDown` instead of `TextBox` to enter numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp?lq=1 This will help you.

Comment: replace `txtHours.Text` with `double.Parse(txtHours.Text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the parsing will work, that's why the double.Parse() method exists.
You could use it like this

```
txtCost.Text = (double.Parse(txtHours.Text) * costPerHour + costOfInsurance).ToString();
```

you're converting `txtHours.Text` to `double`, multiplying it with `costPerHour` and adding `CostOfInsurance`. After that is calculated, result is converted to `string` and put into `txtCost` control

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me I guess, I was doing the parse wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
                txtCost.Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(txtHours.Text.ToString())) * costPerHour + costOfInsurance).ToString();`

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
    txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text * costPerHour + costOfInsurance;
else
    txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text * costPerHour;
```

by

```
if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
    txtCost.Text
        = (Convert.ToDouble(txtHours.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(costPerHour) + costOfInsurance)
          .ToString();
else
    txtCost.Text
        = (Convert.ToDouble(txtHours.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(costPerHour))
          .ToString();
```

to introduce some parsing, but this will not have meaningful error handling. An `exception` will be thrown if the contents of `costPerHour` cannot be parsed.

Comment: this didn't work either. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What exactly 'didn't work'? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Codor, you still have `string` (`txtHours.Text`) that you're trying to multiply with double.

Comment: Thans for the hint, I was overlooking that.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply convert string value in int or double as per your requirement

```
 if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
    txtCost.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) * costPerHour + costOfInsurance).ToString();
 else
    txtCost.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) * costPerHour).ToString();
```

What for this you must validated text box value because if it wasn't the numeric value it generate exception

Answer (score 0):

Using this extension methods

```
public static string GetSumMul(this string input, double num1, double num2)
    {
        var textBoxValue = Convert.ToDouble(input); // this might throw FormatException or OverflowException
        return ((textBoxValue*num1) + num2).ToString();
    }

    public static string GetMul(this string input, double num1)
    {
        var textBoxValue = Convert.ToDouble(input); // this might throw FormatException or OverflowException
        return (textBoxValue * num1).ToString();
    }
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double costPerHour = 3.00;
        double costOfInsurance = 1.00;
        try
        {
            if (chbInsurance.Checked == true)
                txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text.GetSumMul( costPerHour ,costOfInsurance);
            else
                txtCost.Text = txtHours.Text.GetMul( costPerHour);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            //"Unable to convert txtCost.Text to a Double."
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            //" txtCost.Text is outside the range of a Double."

        }

    }
```