# Cannot convert from 'double' to 'string' -> Listview subitem

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, double

I'm really having a hard time with this. This code is suppose to be solving a total payment and put it into the sub total `TextBox`, but when i try to convert it to `double` (because the prices have `decimals`), this is what it came up with. I've tried `int` and it didnt have any problems.

Any solutions for this?

```
double i = 0;
double j = 0;
double k = 0;
i = 0;
j = 0;
k = 0;

try
{
    j = lstvProds.Items.Count;
    for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++)
    {
        k = k + Convert.ToDouble(lstvProds.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
    }

    //double l = Convert.ToDouble(k);

}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
return k;
```

Comment: oops sorry! it's there now

Comment: why is i declared as double? try using int as type for i...

Comment: will try! @Philip

Comment: This question is not unique. Please read [ask] and share your research. It just means that for some value of `i`, `lstvProds.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text` will return a value that cannot be parsed as double. See for example the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp). If that doesn't answer your question, then [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including the input for which this code fails. Edit: alright, reopened, the problem was the `ListView.Items.Item[string]`  indexer being resolved for a call with a `double`...

Comment: @PhilipW has a good point, but that's not what is wrong here. Try stepping through each iteration of the for loop. What is the last value you see for lstvProds.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text before the exception is thrown?

Comment: @philipw, that worked like a charm XD i just realized it now! THANK YOU SO MUCH ^w^

Comment: Thats the problem with the ListView: everything is string and you need code to convert it back (and populate each cell).  Use a DataGridView and you can retain the datatype

Comment: Thank you guys for your time and help! ^w^ Appreciated!~

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, I convert my comment to an answer and elaborate the underlying problem:

To be clear: The problem was a compile error, not an exception during runtime.

The reason for it was the following part:

```
lstvProds.Items[i]
```

The Items[] operator is overloaded with a string and an integer parameter. The integer version returns the ith element, the string version looks for a matching item in the list with the same name.

That's the reason for the Error: 'i' is a double. Used with an integer, everything is fine...

PS: parsing the double to a string could lead to a completly different functionality...