# How to retrieve values of multiple txtBoxes and display sum in a new page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-page-postback

On Page1.aspx I have 3 txtBoxes with Compare Validators that ensure they are of type Currency.

On Page2.aspx I have another text box called txtResult whose job it is to display the sum of the other 3 txtBoxes when btnCalculate is clicked on Page1.

Problem: I can't get the 3 txtBoxes to be treated as doubles and not strings. If txtBox values are 1, 3, and 8, txtResult will be 138 and not 12.

I tried try parsing but <s>it wasn't allowed</s> failed to compile.

Code behind Page1:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");
    }
}
```

Code behind Page2:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Page lastPage = (Page)Context.Handler;
    txtResult.Text = ((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtGross")).Text
        + ((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtValueOfAssets")).Text
        + ((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtInvestments")).Text;
}
```

Attempt to use `TryParse`:

```
txtResult.Text = 
    double.TryParse(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtGross")).‌​Text, out gross);
```

Errors with:

> Cannot implicitly covert bool to string

Comment: Alexei, maybe I did it incorrectly but initially I tried the following:
`txtResult.Text = double.TryParse(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtGross")).Text, out gross);`
where gross is a double.... and I got "Cannot implicitly covert bool to string"

Comment: For future questions specify exactly what happens ("not allowed" implies there are some outside restrictions and not compile error). I've edited in your comment and close question as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the appropriate edit and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Double.Parse(text) to convert the text into a double. So for example:

```
txtResult.Text = (Double.Parse(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtGross")).Text)
    + Double.Parse(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtValueOfAssets")).Text)
    + Double.Parse(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtInvestments")).Text)).ToString();
```

Notice that I needed to wrap the whole thing in a .ToString() to convert the answer back to text so that it can be assigned to `txtResult.Text`.  I provided the answer in on long statement since the questions used one long statement but typically I convert each of the values to a double and place them in individual double vars then I'd add those in another statement, and finally in yet another statement I'd convert the answer to a string and place it in the text box.  I find such a multi statement approach easier to read and digest, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Ah! I kept `ToString()`ing every line in that statement. I find the multi statement approach easier too. Thanks!

Comment: OP specified that "I tried try parsing but it wasn't allowed." - so this is not an answer to question as asked. Otherwise you should have just voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question he asked was "How to retrieve values of multiple txtBoxes and display sum in a new page?" and he provided non working code which he wanted help making work.  I provided exactly that. Please remove your down vote.

Comment: OP specified that parsing was *not allowed* - so far I don't see what alternatives are allowed (or even if that statement actually mean what it states), but `Double.Parse` does not look like acceptable option for this question as asked. Clearly they know about `Double.Parse`/`Double.TryParse` based on that line...

Comment: Turned out OP just used random words...

Comment: The code I provided uses Double.Parse and does work and it answers the question "How to retrieve values of multiple txtBoxes and display sum in a new page?" when taken together with the code he posted

Answer (score 0):

Text property of TextBox is a String type so adding them will result in concatenation. You need to convert the Text value to double before adding.

A simple way of converting is `Convert.ToDouble("")`

so try this:
`txtResult.Text = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtGross")).Text)
        + Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtValueOfAssets")).Text)
        + Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtInvestments")).Text);`

Comment: OP specified that "I tried try parsing but it wasn't allowed." - so this is not an answer to question as asked. Otherwise you should have just voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your values are strings, they are being treated as strings, and are concatenating.

You need to convert those values to Double first, and then do your addition.

This post here talks about a few methods for converting to double:  [Converting string to double in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp)

In essence, you can use the Convert.ToDouble() method to convert your text box Text value, to a double.

```
Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("txtValueOfAssets")).Text)
```

The best approach, would be to look into the TryParse() method, to ensure that your code doesn't break if fed a non-numeric string.

Comment: OP specified that "I tried try parsing but it wasn't allowed." - so this is not an answer to question as asked. Otherwise you should have just voted to close as duplicate.