# Trouble Converting String to Double

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make it so that when a button is clicked it takes strings from two text boxes and converts them to doubles. However, every time I try to debug it, upon clicking the button the compiler tells me "input string was not in a correct format." I'm not really sure why it isn't working. Here's the code for the button click:

```
protected void btnCalculateSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double annualHours = 0.0;
    double payRate = 0.0;
    double annualSalary = 0.0;

    annualHours = Convert.ToDouble(lblAnnualHours.Text);
    payRate = Convert.ToDouble(lblPayRate.Text);

    annualSalary = annualHours * payRate;

    lblAnnualSalary.Text = "Annual Salary: $" + annualSalary.ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp

Comment: What is the text in lblAnnualHours.Text and lblPayRate.Text ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to double in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you sure that `lblAnnualHours` and `lblPayRate` are both textboxes with decimal value? I don't think so (they're labels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you maybe trying to parse the texts of the labels instead of the textboxe`s texts? The names lblAnnualHours and lblPayRate indicate that.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did. I'm always missing little things like this.