# How to find rectangle area, Convert.ToDouble problem

Tags: c#

The problem stands at line 23 and 25.

```
double r.length = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

double r.width = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

I don't know how to make the conversion from string to double so that the program would take double numbers from the user.

My programming teacher once made it but I forgot to note it.

```
class Rectangle
{
    double length;
    double width;
    public double GetArea()
    {
        return length * width;
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length: "+length);
        Console.WriteLine("Width: "+ width);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: "+ GetArea());
    }
}

class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        Console.WriteLine("Length= ");
        double r.length = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // <===
        Console.WriteLine("Width= ");
        double r.width  = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())); // <===
        Console.Writeline("Area= ");
        r.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to double in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399439/converting-string-to-double-in-c-sharp) `Double.TryParse()` is more sppropriate for data coming from the user

Comment: @NoneoftheAbove I'm thinking the problem is at "r.length or r.width" , my IDE has underlined them with red

Comment: The question asks about converting to Double - I posted a link to one of the 2.5 million posts here concerning `c#, double, convert`.  It is entirely possible you have more than one problem.  The error pane describes the underlines to an error message

Comment: The error message is *probably* `'Rectangle' does not contain a definition for 'width'`  Use your mouse to confirm.

Comment: The problem was at declaring the variables. I didnt declare them as "public double length; " but "double length; ". I just started to learn C# from a year+ in C++ world.
Thank you for your generosity! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to fix:

#### `Rectangle`

- Both `length` and `width` should be `public`
- Both `length` and `width` should be properties

  - I.e., they should have `{ get; set; }` appended
- The names for both `length` and `width` should be capitalized because they are properties

  - This is a C# naming convention
- Override `ToString()` for creating a description/string for an object

#### `ExecuteRectangle`

- You don't need the `double` keyword when referencing `r.length` and `r.width` in `ExecuteRectangle`
- To convert a string to a double, use `double.TryParse`

```
class Rectangle
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return Length * Width;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Length: " + Length);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Width: " + Width);
        stringBuilder.Append("Area: " + GetArea());

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

        Console.WriteLine("Length= ");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out r.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Width= ");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out r.Width);

        Console.Writeline("Area= " + r.GetArea());

        Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear! I just added in a couple more edits to improve the code a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Amir Arbabian has stated in his answer, there is another problem. The protection level for `Rectangle.width` and `Rectangle.length` are not specified, so they default to private. To make it accessible, add the public keyword before the `length` and `width` fields in `Rectangle`.

```
public double length;
public double width;
```

One last thing is that you have an extra closing parentheses (`)`) on the line

```
double r.width  = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Simply remove one of the closing parentheses to remove that error. And remove the double keyword, as Amir Arbabian has stated.

Also, what do you need that last `Console.ReadLine()` for?

Comment: It worked man ! Thank you! 
Only problem was at declaring the variables public as you said.
 I only started to shift to C# from 1 year of C++.
As for the last Console.Readline , i must've put it by mistake :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it as

```
r.width = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

without **double** keyword.
You use type only when you declare something, but here you just assign value to field of object.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Please check @Embodiment of Ignorance comment, i've missed that