# always getting string was not recognized as valid datetime. how to convert for current format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-parsing

I want to accept date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format using textbox I have used ajax calendar also.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",null)
```

and

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)
```

are both throwing exception:

> *string was not recognized as valid datetime.*

I know when I will change my system dateformat which is currently `MM-dd-yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy`, it will start recognizing it but what is solution when I will publish it on server.

So is there any solution to parse it for current format ?

Comment: Hm, what is your actual value in the textbox? Maybe it's simply doesn't match the format? If not, try specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the 3rd parameter of ParseExact.

Comment: when we should use null and when InvariantCulture

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `null` means "take the current system language", whereas `InvariantCulture` basically means "make no language-specific substitutions".

Comment: What **exactly** are your users entering into that textbox? Something like `19-05-2012` ? This works just fine for me. Or are the users entering some other format.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an IFormatProvider parameter to the ParseExact method like :

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",provider)
```

And don't forget to use the System.Globalization namespace

Comment: Everyone is giving different solutions but which one should be used. i am confused with these different methods from a long time.

Comment: Basically, with the formatprovider you are specifying what format should the method use to recognize the string you are passing. By default, the system's format is used (if you pass the null value), that's why when you change it in the system, it works. The answers given just cover different situations. My answer simply sets an specific culture, US ("en-US").

Comment: Here is a post about when to use the invariant culture, i think it explains it nicely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture

Comment: Which method you use depends on what you want to do with it. If you only care about a specific format, then use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US") or CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB") or whatever you want. If you want your system to set the value to whatever your users' settings are, then use the method in my answer which uses the `CurrentCulture` from `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`.

Comment: One question Matt, doesn't CurrentThread return the application's process culture, meaning that if you haven't changed it before, it will always return the current system's culture?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to get the user's current settings. Then use that to get the formatted date string.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formattedToCurrentUser = now.ToString(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```