# C# compare string ignoreCase

Tags: c#, string, compare, ignore-case

Within this test method I need to compare the strings of user3 while ignoring case sensitivity. I'm thinking I should use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to ignoreCase.  Is this the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

```
            //set test to get user 
            AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();        

            //call get users
            MembershipUser user1 = prov.GetUser("test.user", false);
            //ask for the username with deliberate case differences
            MembershipUser user2 = prov.GetUser("TeSt.UsEr", false);
            //getting a user with Upper and lower case in the username.
            MembershipUser user3 = prov.GetUser("Test.User", false);

            //prove that you still get the user, 
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, user1);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, user2);

            //test by using the “.ToLower()” function on the resulting string.
            Assert.AreEqual(user1.UserName.ToLower(), user2.UserName.ToLower());
            Assert.AreEqual(user1.UserName, "test.user");
            Assert.AreEqual(user3.UserName, "test.user");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [Assert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243428%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) with the ignoreCase parameter is better because it doesn't require the creation of a new string (and, as pointed out by @dtb, you could work following the rules of a specific culture info)

```
Assert.AreEqual(user1.UserName, user2.UserName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: that was so much simpler than the way I was thinking I was going to have to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

StringInstance.ToUpperInvariant()

```
user1.UserName.ToUpperInvariant() == user3.UserName.ToUpperInvariant();

user3.UserName.ToUpperInvariant() == "TEST.USER";
```

Comment: Comparing strings in a case-insensitive way by converting to upper or lower case does not work in all cultures. Use string comparison methods to compare strings, not case transformations!

Comment: If it works in the culture he's using, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

In it's simple form; you can compare two string while ignoring their case like below.

```
Assert.AreEqual(0,string.Compare("test", "TEST", true));
```

I am not sure; why you need to take the route of non culture specific case since case is a  simple (non localization) unit test case. Having said that, if still you wanted to go on that direction then do refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture) link.