# how to handle culture in double parsing in c#?

Tags: c#, parsing, double, culture

I have a question about how to handle culture while parsing doubles.
In a system price information from various servers comes together.
However the data thats given as input varies in culture.
two million and fifty cents is given as :
"2.000.000,50"
"2,000,000.50"
"2000000.50"
"2000000,50"

is there a generic way to handle these various types of input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no generic way. You either need to know what culture the `double` was formatted or all the servers need to send in a single format, say `InvariantCulture`.

If you guess the culture, there's a bad news waiting for you as different cultures use different decimal separator, group separator etc. So you can't.

[Refer this to foresee what can go wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763887/2530848) if you guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443540/1230816 for an answer to your examples without any cultural assumptions required.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Links to SO are handled the same way.