# datetime conversion issue when i specify format

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code throws an error:

> When converting string to datetime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into datetime object.

CODE:

I need to display default value in text box i.e. current date.

```
txtIssuingDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Then i need to save that in DB too without in specified format

```
ComposedLetterBizz CompLetterBizz = new ComposedLetterBizz(Convert.ToInt32(txtName.Text),  
    Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldComplaintID.Value),  
    txtLetterNo.Text,  
    txtDispatchNo.Text,  
    txtSubject.Text,  
    Convert.ToInt16(ddlDepartments.SelectedValue),  
    Convert.ToInt16(ddlDesignations.SelectedValue),  
    Convert.ToDateTime(txtIssuingDate.Text),  
    Convert.ToDateTime(txtDeadLine.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.Parse` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in case that your culture doesn't use `/` as date-separator:

So instead of

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtIssuingDate.Text)
```

which uses your current-culture's date-separator, this

```
DateTime.Parse(txtIssuingDate.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But then you should also do it when you assign the date to the `TextBox.Text`:

```
txtIssuingDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: @user3518032: it allows to ignore the current culture by using a fake-culture similar to `"en-US"`. This helps to prevent issues that are caused by number or date formatting. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DateTime obj = DateTime.Now;
txtIssuingDate.Text = obj.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
ComposedLetterBizz CompLetterBizz = new ComposedLetterBizz(Convert.ToInt32(txtName.Text), Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldComplaintID.Value), txtLetterNo.Text, txtDispatchNo.Text, txtSubject.Text, Convert.ToInt16(ddlDepartments.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt16(ddlDesignations.SelectedValue),
                obj, Convert.ToDateTime(txtDeadLine.Text));
```

Comment: What different does this offer as a solution??