# How does IIS determine error message language?

Tags: user-interface, iis-7.5, culture, invariantculture

I am running an ASP.NET web site on IIS 7.5 with the culture and UI culture set to Invariant Culture in the settings. Client-based culture is set to false.

The IIS server is running on a German Windows Server 2008 R2, my machine is running English Windows 8.1 with Firefox set to accept en-us content first.

When the app generates an error message this message is in German. I can force it to be in English by changing the culture setting on IIS. Regardless of whether I turn Client-based culture on or off, it will always be in German.

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423391/447490) to a similar question it was suggested that the invariant culture is based on English. Therefore I would assume error messages to be output in English.

How does IIS determine the language of the error message to output?