# How do I programm a language independent double.tryparse?

Tags: c#, double

i got string values representing doubles. (f.e. "1.23"). Always with ".".

If you run the code:

```
double dDouble =0;
string sDemo ="1.23";
double.TryParse(sDemo,out dDouble));
```

it will return 1.23 to the dDouble var.

If i switch to a different languge with "," as "." .... i get 123.0 as dDouble.

How do I ensure that its always 1.23 ...

```
double dDouble =0;
string sDemo ="1.23";
double.TryParse(sDemo,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, 
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dDouble));
```

but I am unsure, if this will solve the problem permanently.

i just tried

Comment: By different language you mean different culture?

Comment: Using the InvariantCulture *is* the recommended way of writing locale-agnostic conversions of numbers and dates.

Comment: In both the end(`double.TryParse` and `double.ToString`), you need to use same culture.

Comment: Do you know the language/culture/format that was used as the double was written as string? If not then you don't stand a chance to parse it correctly. You could try-parse the whole file(or whatever it is) and look which was more successful.

Comment: To the questions:
Original format: English, but's a proprietary software ... no .Net.
Language: German / English / Chineese

Comment: So I will stay with the InvariantCulture statement. Is this Invariant Culture based on the Englisch one?

Comment: @lostbit, ask that question google directly ;) [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9760237/1997232), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2423377/1997232) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 years ago I would solve it like this (do not do that):

```
sDemo = sDemo.Replace(",",".");
```

Now

```
// to string
var text = someDouble.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
// and back
var number = double.Parse(text, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Key point is to use **same** culture. If you convert values for internal use (to example, passing `double` value as a part of text) - use invariant culture. If, however, you want to display it to the user and then read user input, then still *use same culture*: if you don't specify culture for `ToString`, then don't specify it for `Parse`, and if you did, then do it again.