# Responding to Invalid TextBox Entries

Tags: c#

Users enter numbers into textboxes, and the values are displayed on a graph. I want to be sure users type numbers in the textboxes, so I tried:

```
double xValue;
double yValue;

Double.TryParse(xTextBox.Text, out xValue);
Double.TryParse(yTextBox.Text, out yValue);

chart1.Series["data1"].Points.AddXY(xValue, yValue);
```

`Double.TryParse()` validates whether users type numbers, but I'm not sure how to code for when users *don't* type numbers. `Double.TryParse()` will assign `xValue` or `yValue` a 0--but I also want users to be able to enter 0 values so I cannot just code something like

```
if (xValue!=0 && yValue!=0)...
```

Something like

```
if (xTextBox.Text!="0") {
  Double.TryParse(xTextBox.Text, out xValue);
  }
```

seems like awkward code that will just get more. What's the standard way to make sure users entered a double?

Comment: What do you mean by _but I also want users to be able to enter 0 values_? They actually can. If `Double.TryParse` fails, this method will assing the out parameter to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a boolean which is true if the conversion succeeded, and false if it failed.

```
if (!Double.TryParse(xTextBox.Text, out xValue)) {
     // handle a failure to convert here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double.TryParse returns a boolean if parsing was a success, and you should check the results of Double.TryParse not the xValue and yValue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to take into consideration **the user locale settings**. For example in USA the decimal separator is `.` and in my country it is `,`. So you need to specify the format when user enters double values or replace `,` with `.` and then parse values with `Invariant culture`.

Second `Double.TryParse` method returns `bool` value which you can use to check whether the entered value is successfully parsed as double.

Comment: +1 for mentioning invariant culture [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture] which I did not know about.