# How does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and DateTime to String works

Tags: c#, sql-server, localization, format, cultureinfo

I've been looking for information on Internet about this optional parameter CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when formatting in .NET

These articles explains about it: [What does cultureinfo invariantculture mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean) , [What is the invariant culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture). But it's still not clear for me.

I want to manage and save a datetime variable as this format 'yyyyMMdd' and I formatted it like this:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Today; //> 2016-02-10 12:33
string formattedDateTime = localDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); //> 20160210
```

It is suppossed to have a varchar column in db with a length of 8. But in a specific case it started to save 7 chars. I'm waiting to get access to our client's domain to check the saved format.

However, each user can set no matter what culture in the system (e.g. "en", "es", "fr"), so even if the method ToString which is forced to format like this "YYYYMMDD", do I need to set the invariant culture? If not, I could risk to have my datetime in string with another format? Does the regional configuration in database server matter?

This is that I'm attempting to do right now, but not sure if this will fix the problem after we check in tests:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Today;
string formattedDateTime = localDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //> 20160210
```

This is another scope, if I need to build my variable from database and save it in a stored procedure, I'm doing this:

```
CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 112) --ISO for yyyymmdd
```

---

**EDIT:**

We did some tests:

```
DateTime currentDateTime = dateParameter; // 10/2/16 12:33 PM
string dateParameterAsString = dateParameter.ToString(); // "10/2/16 12:33 PM"
string formattedIdentifier = dateParameter.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // "02/10/2016 12:33:00"
string formattedIdentifier2 = dateParamter.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); // "20160218"
string formattedIdentifier3 = dateParamter.ToString("yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // "20160218"
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't store datetime information as character data. Store it as date or datetime.

Comment: If you're trying to do the conversion purely for building a SQL string, you'd be better off using `SqlParameter`s

Comment: @SeanLange In fact we are using a datime column in db for this datetime value. However, according to some evaluations in our processes, we are saving this value as identifier for biz purposes in another column.

Comment: YYYMMDD is not a correct format string to convert a datetime to a string. (_yyyyMMdd_) and with this format you don't need any CultureInfo, but go back to comment #1 please

Comment: culture determines the order (month or day first) separators or the actually language to display the month names in for default and standard formats.  When you specify a custom one that does not use separators or the name of the month then culture really doesn't come into play.

Comment: @Steve Sorry. It's a typo. Corrected!

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all if the reason you got 7 characters was due to using a non-Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @SeanLange sqlite doesnt support datetime. you have no other option than string

Comment: @batmaci this question is clearly marked with sql server which does have a datetime datatype. The fact that sqlite doesn't is a clear indication that it is a technology I would run away from as fast as possible. What a massive shortcoming.

Comment: @SeanLange it is a very unfortunate technology but it doesnt leave any other option for mobile development if someone wants a local database

Answer (score 3):

For your particular use case, specifying the culture explicitly as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` isn't absolutely necessary.

For the format string `"yyyyMMdd"`, all of the components will output just integer characters, and happen to be unaffected by culture. Using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` might be a small performance improvement (avoids having to lookup the current thread's culture), and isn't a bad thing to get in the habit of if you want to develop against very specific information. It would only be an issue if you were using `"ddd"` or anything else that involves the name of the month, day, etc. (or simply using `.ToString()` without parameters, which would have the entire thing determined by the current thread's culture)

That said, let's look at the other issue here: you're creating strings to store in your database. Why is this being done here rather than in the presentation layer? Are you not using parameterized queries?

Please, please please use parameterized queries. See [How and Why to Use Parameterized Queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. It's not calculated at presentation layer. It's done within a service library which receives all the parameters and once calculated, all the data is managed with a ORM library that uses SqlParameters inside. We're analyzing at this moment the service method which performs this calculation. I'm afraid that in cases where the datetime is 2016-02-01, it is being saved as 201621 (6 chars)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments, you have a datetime field and you are going to have a character representation of that. In this case I suggest you use a computed column and do everything in database level.