# Short.Parse with decimal fails

Tags: c#, tryparse

I have a decimal value

```
decimal myDecimal = 19.0000M;
```

I'm trying to convert this to a short value.

```
short newVal;
short.TryParse(myDecimal.ToString(), out newVal); // False
```

but this fails. If I use a double it is fine.

Why does this fail?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `mydecimal.ToString()`? What's your locale?

Comment: myDecimal.ToSting() returns "19.0000".

Comment: From `decimal` to `string` to `int`? Maybe there is an [even more complicated and error prone way](https://twitter.com/ckolderup/status/789002880246177792) available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Problem

- The problem is that this overload of `TryParse` takes that number as
  an `NumberStyles.Integer` - meaning it is looking for a format that
  does not contain any `.`. seeing in [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int16.cs,653231caefa35c51) it is
  actually doing this:

  ```
  public static bool TryParse(String s, out Int16 result) {
     return TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out result);
  }
  ```
- To show that the `.` is the problem change as following and it will
  work:

  ```
  decimal myDecimal = 19M;
  var succeeded = short.TryParse(myDecimal.ToString(), out newVal);
  ```

> How Does **Double work** but **decimal fails**

The reason why with double it works is because of how it is returned in the `ToString`:

```
decimal val1 = 19.00M;
double val2 = 19.00;

val1.ToString() // "19.00"
val2.ToString() // "19"
```

> The Fix

To be able to parse your original input use instead the overload where you  provide the `NumberStyle` and `Format`:

```
var succeeded = short.TryParse(myDecimal.ToString(), NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo,  out newVal);
```

*The `NumberStyle.Number` allows:*

- *`AllowLeadingWhite`,  `AllowTrailingWhite`,  `AllowLeadingSign`, 
  `AllowTrailingSign`, `AllowDecimalPoint`, `AllowThousands`*

Comment: From decimal to string to int? Maybe there is an even more complicated way available?

Comment: @UweKeim - That is how he is doing in the question. This is just providing a way of how to use what he is doing but that will work

Comment: Yeah, sorry, will post my comment at the appropriate location .

Comment: @Jim - In your computer the culture is different and probably uses `,` as the symbol for a decimal point. Change the `.` to `,` and try. The `InvariantCulture` is based on English. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture)

Answer (score 4):

including culture and number style will be better approach:

```
short.TryParse(myDecimal.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out newVal);
```

Comment: This is correct but, why is this only working with `CurrentCulture` on my pc ?

Comment: Your current culture probably uses some different number format

Answer (score 1):

You should `AllowDecimalPoint` with parsing of short in other case the parsing will fail: [**DonNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBziSf)

```
decimal myDecimal = 19.0000M;
short newVal;

short.TryParse(myDecimal.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out newVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, decimal saves digits after floating point as well. So, mathematicaly equal numbers will give different effect when printed:

```
decimal myDecimal = 19.0000M;
decimal myDecimal2 = 19.000000M;
Console.WriteLine(myDecimal.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(myDecimal2.ToString());

//OUTPUT
19,0000
19,000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because myDecimal.ToString() returns a decimal number string: 19.000 and short.Tryparse() accepts only integer strings.

The solution is not to convert to string but directly between decimal and short (as luki shows):

short shortVal = Convert.ToInt16(myDecimal);

Answer (score -2):

Try:
    Convert.ToInt16(myDecimal);

Comment: I can try a lot, but I would prefer an answer and an explanation why it works and why the original approach does not work

Comment: In default version of TryParse method input parameter s(string) is interpretted using NumberStyles.Integer style , so you will be able to input only string with digits and optional white spaces and sign character. In your example your input string contains decimal delimeter character so TryParse method returns false. If you want to use this method to parse your input you have to use this method:

Comment: public static bool TryParse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, out short result)